Prove $\,9\mid 2^{k_1}(2^{2k_2 + 3k_3 + 1 + (-1)^{k_3}} \!\! - 2^{2k_2 - (k_3\bmod 2)}\!-3)\,$ for all $\,k_i\ge 1$
I want to prove that for any positive integers $k_1, k_2, k_3 \geq1$:
$$
2^{k_1 + 2k_2 + 3k_3 + 1 + (-1)^{k_3}} - 3 \cdot 2^{k_1} - 2^{k_1 + 2k_2 - O(k_3)} \equiv 0 \pmod{9}
$$
where:
$$
O(k) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } k \text{ is odd} \\
0 & \text{if } k \text{ is even}
\end{cases}
$$
This expression appears to simplify to $0 \pmod{9}$ for any positive integers $k_1, k_2, k_3 \geq1$, but I am looking for a formal proof or insights on how to demonstrate this rigorously.
UPDATE
so from the comments below we could reduce the
above to the following:
$$
2^{2k_2 + 3k_3 + 1 + (-1)^{k_3}} - 2^{2k_2 - O(k_3)} \equiv 3 \pmod{9}
$$
By factoring the $2^{k_1}$:
$$
2^{k_1}\cdot(2^{2k_2 + 3k_3 + 1 + (-1)^{k_3}} -3 - 2^{2k_2 - O(k_3)}) \equiv 0 \pmod{9}
$$
and noting that $2^{k_1}$is $\not\equiv 0 \pmod{9}$ the second expression can be taken to be $ \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$ and then adding 3 to both sides
Emperically
I also ran a script to generate and check values real quick and here are the results
First Term:
$2^{(2k_2 + 3k_3 + 1 + (-1)^{k_3})} \pmod{9} $



$k_2--k_3$
1
2
3
4
5




1
5
7
5
7
5


2
2
1
2
1
2


3
8
4
8
4
8


4
5
7
5
7
5


5
2
1
2
1
2



Second Term:
$2^{(2k_2 - O(k_3))} \pmod{9}$



$k_2--k_3$
1
2
3
4
5




1
2
4
2
4
2


2
8
7
8
7
8


3
5
1
5
1
5


4
2
4
2
4
2


5
8
7
8
7
8



After computing the differences, we find that all values are congruent to $3\pmod{9}$



$k_2--k_3$
1
2
3
4
5




1
3
3
3
3
3


2
-6
-6
-6
-6
-6


3
3
3
3
3
3


4
3
3
3
3
3


5
-6
-6
-6
-6
-6



noting that $-6 \equiv 3 \pmod{9}$ and $3\equiv 3 \pmod{9}$
Now the question, how can we prove this in notation, and not just via numbers and such computation? Or should we take case by case?

Hello and welcome to Math.SE! Can you provide more information's like why are you asking this, where does this question come from and what did you try / what are you thoughts? Currently the question is just "This is my problem. Solve it." and that doesn't meet the site's standards.

I put k1=k2=k3=1 and did not get 0 mod 9?

@trula for $k_1=k_2=k_3=1$ I get $2^6-3.2-2^2=64-10=54 =0 \mod 9$, so the identity holds in this case.

Can you explain how you arrived at the expression on the left of the congruence? It might be helpful to note that $2$ is a unit modulo $9$, since $2^6=1\mod 9$. It follows, for example, that the identity is equivalent to the one you obtain by setting $k_1=0$.

This expression emerged from my own research on the Collatz conjecture. I have set it up according to pure empirical evidence.

Cancelling $2^{k_1}$ and noting $!\bmod 9!:,\ 3\cdot 4\equiv 3\Rightarrow 3\cdot 4^{k_2}\equiv 3,,$ it reduces to $2^{1+(-1)^{k_3}}(-1)^{k_3} \equiv 3+ 2^{-(k_3\bmod 2)},,$ which is true, being true for both odd & even $k\ \ $

@BillDubuque Thank you so much. I am a bit new to this, so do you mind writing an elaborative answer? I did not understand the reduction

Cancel $\,2^{\large k_1}\!$ to reduce to
$\:\!\color{#0a0}{4^{\large k_2}}(\overbrace{\color{#c00}{(-1)^{\large k}\:\!2^{\large 1+(-1)^{\large k}}\!\!-2^{\:\!\large -(k\bmod 2)}}}^{\large\color{#c00}X}) \equiv 3\pmod{\!9},\, k\! =\! k_3$.
Hence  it suffices to show $\,\color{#c00}{X\equiv 3},\,$ since $\,\color{#0a0}4(3)\equiv 3\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{4^n}(3)\equiv 3\,$ by induction.
But $\,k\,$ even $\Rightarrow \color{#c00}X\equiv 4-1\equiv\color{#c00}3,\:$ and $\,k\,$ odd $\Rightarrow \color{#c00}X\equiv -1+4\equiv \color{#c00}3.$ $\ \ \small\bf QED$

Thank you for the elaboration. How did the term in the X above change from $2^{3k_3}$ to $(-1)^{k_{3}}$

@Hou $,2^{3K}!=(\color{#0af}{2^3})^K\equiv (\color{#0af}{-1})^K.,$ Also I used $,2^{-1}\equiv -4,,$ by $,{-}4(2)\equiv 1,$ (in $,k_3,$ odd case). $\ \ $

You are in fact almost there.
The Carmichael function of $9$ is $6$ and $2$ is prime to $9$, so your powers will replicate $\bmod9$ when the exponents replicate $\bmod6$ and are nonnegative.
To guarantee nonnegativity of the exponents, extend your table to include $k_2=6$ and $k_3=6$. If your expression remains $\equiv0\bmod9$ for the additional cases, you have completed the "truth table" for your claim.

Thank you for the insight, it is an interesting new concept to me. It does extend to $k_2=6$ and $k_3=6$ similar to the above. But does this mean that I will need to construct the entire truth table for as large as Carmichael function gets? Not specifically in this scenario but in general
